# Strategies to deal with \ being in an awkward place on the keyboard?

Tags: macros, editors, keyboard

So, I'm typing on a standard EN-US Qwerty keyboard, where the <kbd>\</kbd> key is in the top right below the backspace key. I find that LaTeX requires me to repeatedly type this key for macros and such, and that my wrists tend to get quite sore from constantly reaching for it.

I'm wondering, what strategies have been used to make this easier, both from an efficiency and an ergonomics standpoint? I realize that this question is fairly open ended, so there probably won't be one "right" answer, but I'm curious what different things people have done to overcome this over the years.

Comment: using the en_US keyboard is actually much more comfortable than using the de_DE Keyboard where the  `\`is located besides the `0` as third key so you have to press `CTRL + ALT` or `ALT GR` to insert the `\` character

Comment: Emacs.  Do I have to say anything more?  Ah, yes.  AUCTeX.  (And now the problem of "backslash is hard to reach" gets replaced by "control is hard to reach".  But this is basically solved, see e.g. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey)

Comment: I'm not overly familar with Emacs. I was taught Vim in school, though I was never overly fond of it. Is the idea just that you use an Emacs macro to simulate "\"?

Comment: Standard typing dictates that you should press "\" with right-hand little finger and `B` with left-hand point finger. I've seen many people type `B` with right-hand due to the fact that it is somehow in the middle. I'm not saying you're doing the same, but if you do, it might be the reason to this exhaust. A part from that, you can use `snippets` if your editor provides them (e.g. gedit does). I've found them very handy for programming. Finally, you can try to map "\" to another key if your operating system allows you to do so.

Comment: @jmite: in Emacs+AUCTeX, you hardly ever *have* to press backslash: `C-c C-m` starts entering a (La)TeX macro (with autocompletion, of course).  Also, `C-c C-e` inserts an environment template.  Etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can try changing your layout to Spanish.

All the letter will be the in the same place (Spanish only has one extra letter: `ñ`, which will be where the `;` is.

The `\` will be on your top left corner left to the `1`.

Take a look at this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to remap keys as you please.  It is easy on systems where [xmodmap](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/xmodmap.1.html) is available.  (In this example, I'm using Ubuntu 12.10).  We can, e.g., remap 'caps lock' to be 'backslash' using the following command.

[**EDIT:** I forgot the caps lock requires special handling to avoid having it continue to switch between its normal toggling between caps and lowercase.  For this example, it is important to run this command as well: `xmodmap -e "clear lock"`.]

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = backslash"
```

In order to find out what keycode you need, you use [xev](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xev.1.html).  Open a terminal and type: `xev`.  Then while it is active, if you hit the backslash key, you'll get the following output in the terminal (I'm using a standard US layout with dead keys):

```
KeyPress event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0xc8, subw 0x0, time 13613662, (85,91), root:(1712,536),
    state 0x10, keycode 51 (keysym 0x5c, backslash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5c) "\"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5c) "\"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Caps lock will give you:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0xc8, subw 0x0, time 13611758, (85,91), root:(1712,536),
    state 0x12, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Thus, the `xmodmap` command has mapped `keycode 66` to `backslash`.  But this will only work for the current X session. If you want to make the switch permanent, you can do this command (after the first `xmodmap`):

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmodmaprc
```

which gives you an `xmodmap`-readable file in your home directory which includes your recent modifications, and which should be read at the start of the current user's subsequent sessions.